# Can't update certain database tables in Flask app (Flask-SQLAlchemy)

Tags: mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Flask app novice trying to resolve a perplexing problem. I have an app that allows users to add records to database tables, and, with appropriate permissions, edit those records. There is no problem with adding records to any of the tables. However, for **only certain** tables, the submitted edits do not actually change the table values.

As an example, I cannot get the 'teaching_set_registry' table to update, but the 'teaching_set_cases' table works fine:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class teaching_set_registry(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "teaching_set_registry"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    created_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    created_by = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    service = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    organ = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=True)
    unknowns = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    unknowns_date = db.Column(db.Date)
    unknowns_presenter = db.Column(db.String(100))
    is_deleted = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

class teaching_set_cases(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'teaching_set_cases'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ts_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    created_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    clinical_history = db.Column(db.String(500))
    diagnosis = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=True)
    notes = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)
    is_deleted = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
```

Here is the corresponding "non-working" route. All of the debug print statements return expected values and there are no errors. The table just doesn't update.

```
### DOES NOT WORK TO UPDATE TABLE ###

@pathmm_bp.route('/delete_teaching_set', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def delete_teaching_set():
    print("Delete teaching set route activated")
    
    if not (current_user.role == 'Attending'):
        flash("You do not have permission to access this page.", 'danger')
        return redirect(url_for('pathmm.index'))
    
    teaching_set_id = request.form.get('teaching_set_id')
    print("Teaching set ID for deletion", teaching_set_id)
    
    # Fetch the record from the database
    teaching_set = teaching_set_registry.query.get(teaching_set_id)
    print("Matching teaching set:", teaching_set)

    if teaching_set:
        teaching_set.is_deleted = True
        
        try:            
            db.session.commit()
            print("Teaching set marked as deleted successfully.")
            return jsonify({'success': 'Case deleted successfully'})
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error during commit:", e)  # Log the exception
            db.session.rollback()
            return jsonify({'error': 'Error deleting case'}), 500

    return jsonify({'error': 'Case not found'}), 404
```

For reference, this route updates the teaching_set_cases table as expected:

```
### WORKS ###

@pathmm_bp.route('/delete_teaching_set_case', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def delete_teaching_set_case():

    if not (current_user.role == 'Attending'):
        flash("You do not have permission to access this page.", 'danger')
        return redirect(url_for('pathmm.index'))
    
    teaching_set_case_id = request.form.get('teaching_set_case_id')
    
    # Fetch the record from the database
    teaching_set_case = teaching_set_cases.query.get(teaching_set_case_id)

    if teaching_set_case:
        teaching_set_case.is_deleted = True

        try:
            db.session.commit()
            return jsonify({'success': 'Case deleted successfully'})
        except Exception as e:
            db.session.rollback()
            return jsonify({'error': 'Error deleting case'}), 500

    return jsonify({'error': 'Case not found'}), 404
```

I can confirm that the teaching_sets_registry table can be updated via a direct mysql update statement from the terminal:

```
UPDATE teaching_set_registry SET is_deleted = True WHERE id=12
    -> ;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

Given that I see no difference in the syntax between the working and non-working routes, I'm a bit at a loss as to why some tables are updating and others are not. All of the debug statements appear to show the expected values and I am not seeing any console errors. Any thoughts on things to try? Thanks all...